# Unable to start Openshift Origin 3.11 on Single VM

Tags: linux, kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin, centos8

I am trying to run OpenShift origin 3.11 on the Centos8 box in a All-In-One mode.
I have executed all the necessary steps as per the link :
https://opensource.com/article/18/11/local-okd-cluster-linux

While trying to make the cluster up with the command :
oc cluster up
Cluster is up and running with no issues. Then when I want to run the Openshift Cluster with the command : oc cluster up --public-hostname=103.231.8.164 , it is failing with the below error:

> quote
> I1021 16:48:50.515745   21486 run_self_hosted.go:557] Server isn't healthy yet.  Waiting a little while. Get https://103.231.8.164:8443/healthz?timeout=32s: dial tcp 103.231.8.164:8443: connect: connection refused
> I1021 16:48:51.516680   21486 run_self_hosted.go:557] Server isn't healthy yet.  Waiting a little while. Get https://103.231.8.164:8443/healthz?timeout=32s: dial tcp 103.231.8.164:8443: connect: connection refused
> I1021 16:48:51.517328   21486 run_self_hosted.go:557] Server isn't healthy yet.  Waiting a little while. Get https://103.231.8.164:8443/healthz?timeout=32s: dial tcp 103.231.8.164:8443: connect: connection refused
> E1021 16:48:51.517364   21486 run_self_hosted.go:571] API server error: Get https://103.231.8.164:8443/healthz?timeout=32s: dial tcp 103.231.8.164:8443: connect: connection refused ()
> Error: timed out waiting for the condition

Answer (score 0):

May i ask why you want to use 3.11?

openshift v3 installation worked for me, only via ansible installation (https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/tree/release-3.11)

I would go for v4+ because its way cooler and easier to handle/setup :
https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/deploy-openshift-at-the-edge-with-single-node-openshift